# Save the signatureView.signature as a binding variable for another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, signature

I am saving the signatureView.signature into a variable and outputting it directly as an image.

```
@State private var signatureImage: UIImage? 
@Binding var signature: String


SignatureCaptureView(signatureImage: $signatureImage) 
    .frame(height: 200) 
    .border(Color.gray, width: 1)


if let img = signatureImage {
        .Image(uiImage: img)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        .id(UUID())
} else {
    Text("Noch keine Unterschrift")
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
}
```

But it does not show the Last Drawing. So if I draw 2 strokes, it only shows the first one. If I draw 3 lines, it only shows the first two. So it always does NOT show the last one.

SignatureCaptureView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftSignatureView


struct SignatureCaptureView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var signatureImage: UIImage?
    private var signatureView: SwiftSignatureView // Diese Eigenschaft hinzufügen
    var coordinator: Coordinator? // Füge ein Coordinator-Objekt hinzu

    func getCroppedSignature(from view: SwiftSignatureView) -> UIImage? {
        return view.getCroppedSignature()
    }

    init(signatureImage: Binding<UIImage?>) {
        self._signatureImage = signatureImage
        self.signatureView = SwiftSignatureView()
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SwiftSignatureView {
        let signatureView = SwiftSignatureView()
        signatureView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return signatureView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SwiftSignatureView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, SwiftSignatureViewDelegate {
        var parent: SignatureCaptureView
        var signatureView: PencilKitSignatureView? // Speichere die SignatureView


        init(_ parent: SignatureCaptureView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        
        func updateUIView(_ view: ISignatureView) {
            if let signatureView = view as? PencilKitSignatureView {
                parent.signatureImage = signatureView.signature
                view.signature = signatureView.signature
            }
            
        }

        func swiftSignatureViewDidDrawGesture(_ view: ISignatureView, _ tap: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            //print("triggered: DrawGesture")
            if let signatureView = view as? PencilKitSignatureView {
                //parent.signatureImage = signatureView.signature
            }
        }

        func swiftSignatureViewDidDraw(_ view: ISignatureView) {
            print("triggered: DidDraw")
            if let signatureView = view as? PencilKitSignatureView {
                print("saving...")
               parent.signatureImage = signatureView.signature
            } else {
                print("View konnte nicht zu PencilKitSignatureView gecastet werden")
            }
        }






    }
}
```

My SignatureView to reproduce the whole code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftSignatureView

struct SignatureView: View {
    @State private var signatureImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var signature: String


    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Bitte unterschreiben:")
                .font(.headline)
            
            SignatureCaptureView(signatureImage: $signatureImage)
                .frame(height: 200)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
        }
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Button("Speichern") {
                    if let img = signatureImage {
                        if let data = img.pngData() {
                            signature = data.base64EncodedString()
                        } else {
                            print("Fehler bei der Datenkonvertierung")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Kein Bild vorhanden")
                    }
                }



                Button("Zurücksetzen") {
                    signatureImage = nil
                    // Hier können Sie die Unterschrift zurücksetzen, wenn nötig
                }
            }

            // Hier wird das Bild der Unterschrift (oder ein Platzhalter) angezeigt
            ZStack {
                if let img = signatureImage {
                    Image(uiImage: img)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .id(UUID())
                } else {
                    Text("Noch keine Unterschrift")
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I Draw 2 "Lines"

[image: Image No 1]

I draw the last Line (the 3 inbetween the 1 and 2)

[image: Image No 2]

Comment: You aren't showing enough code to reproduce the issue, but the problem likely has to do with the fact that you don't do anything in `updateUIView` - that should be where you *update* a view with any new information after it's initial creation in the `makeUIView` function

Comment: @jnpdx i added not my View which works with the SignatureCaptureView. You shall be aple to reproduce it now.

Comment: Be aware that the `@State`/`@Binding` pair is for value types. `UIImage` is reference type.

Comment: Without a [mre], it's not possible for anyone else to fully debug this and provide a concrete answer.

Comment: @jnpdx With the 2 Files i fully copied & pasted here, is it easy to reproduce it. :)

Answer (score 0):

After you finish drawing, just call the update function like this:

```
func swiftSignatureViewDidDraw(_ view: ISignatureView) {
    updateUIView(_ view: view)
}
```

And you can move this block to update function since it's already partially doing it

```
func updateUIView(_ view: ISignatureView) {
    if let signatureView = view as? PencilKitSignatureView {
        parent.signatureImage = signatureView.signature
        //view.signature = signatureView.signature 
        //no need because signatureView already came from view, besides I think it is "let" parameter and will not allow you to assign.
    } else {
        print("View konnte nicht zu PencilKitSignatureView gecastet werden")
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s not how SwiftUI works (you don’t call updateUIView manually) and your call site isn’t valid Swift code.

Comment: It doesn't work like that in Swift. I had already tried other ways...

Apparently the variable signatureImage is a back. For whatever reason.